# How to extract/reading/convert information from Excel cell to WebView or TextView keeping format?

Tags: android, excel, apache-poi

How to extract/reading/convert information from cell of exsel to webview or textview keeping format?

```
Workbook wb1 = WorkbookFactory.create(getAssets().open("bos2.xls"));
    Sheet sheet = wb1.getSheetAt(0);
    Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
    Cell prim = row.getCell(2);

    string text = prim.getStringCellValue();

    WebView myWebView2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);
    myWebView2.setBackgroundColor(0);
    String sum = "<!Doctype html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8></head><body>" + text + "</body></html>";
    myWebView2.loadData(sum, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Maybe someone can help me.

Comment: Your code doesn't look like VBA. Can you confirm your tags?

Comment: Of course. It's eclipse.